# stream reliability

Tags: c#

I came across a few posts that where claming that streams are not a reliable data structure, meaning that read/write operations might not follow through in all cases.

So:

a) Is there any truth to this consensus?

b) If so what are the cases in wich read/write operaitions might fail?

This consensus on streams which I came across claims that you sould loop through read/write operations until complete:

```
var bytesRead = 0;
var _packet = new byte[8192];    
while ((bytesRead += file_reader.Read(_packet, bytesRead, _packet.Length - bytesRead)) < _packet.Length) ;
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. If you come across posts that say this or that, and refer to them in your questions, please post links to those posts so that we can see the full context. Perhaps the posts are in error, perhaps there is some specific cases, perhaps just the wording is wrong.

Comment: Do you have any references to the posts you came across? Not calling `Flush` on a stream at the right time may cause undesired effects depending on your scenario, short of a power cut or something similar (and streams are only as reliable as anything else in such extreme cases) the data will get flushed when the stream is closed.

Comment: Please provide links to the posts you found. I Googled `C# stream reliability,` and the only post I found was yours. :) I write code that handles multi-Gigabyte size files using Stream objects with no problems whatsoever.

Answer (score 3):

Well, it depends on what operation you're talking about, and on what layer you consider it a failure.

For instance, if you attempt to read past the end of a stream (ie. read 1000 bytes from a file that only contains 100 bytes, or read a 1000 bytes from a position that is closer to the end of the file than 1000), you will get fewer bytes left. The stream read methods returns the number of bytes they actually managed to read, so you should check that value.

As for write operations, writing to a file might fail if the disk is full, or other similar problems, but in case of write operations you'll get back an exception.

If you're writing to sockets or other network streams, there is no guarantee that even if the Write method returns without exceptions, that the other end is able to receive it, there's a ton of problems that can go wrong along the way.

However, to alleviate your concerns, streams by themselves are not unreliable.

The medium they talk to, however, can be.

Comment: thanks,
im attempting to write throw sockets
the sockets are blocking , but i loop throw the send and receive operaitions as a precuation ,as u said there are a tons of problems that could go wrong 
bytes_sent = 0 ; 
while (bytes_sent < msgBytes.Length)
{
   bytes_sent += client.Send(msgBytes, bytes_sent, msgBytes.Length - bytes_sent, SocketFlags.None); 
}

}

Answer (score 2):

If you follow the documentation, catch and act accordingly when errors occur, I think you'll find streams are pretty much bullet-proof. There's a significant amount of code that has invested in this reliability.

Can we see links to those who claim otherwise? Either you've misunderstood, or they are incorrect.

Comment: im sorry i couldent find them again..that;s whats driving me crazy on this issue ' i just remmeber the point that was given there.